# Redirect when it is empty before question mark

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-7.5

Under IIS 7.5 URL rewrite module, I cannot figure out how it is possible to create a mask that match an URL with empty before the query mark without interfering existing URL like company.com/invoice?id .

Example:

**company.com?test** should redirect to **company.com/en/**

OR

**company.com/?test** should redirect to **company.com/en/**

I tried this rule but it has interfered with **company.com/invoice?id**

```
<rule name="empty url">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/\?.*" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/en/" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my solution:

```
<rule name="empty url">
    <match url="^$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/en/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```